# Visitors can't view the final situation of the site

Tags: permissions

I changed the css style of main page. System account can view the final situation but the visitors can't view. I shared the site with visitors too.Nothing happened. What else should I do? The visitors have the default read permission. I didn't understand why they can't view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the page you changed is not published. You need to check it in and publish it.

Comment: It's checked in but when I publish, an error occurs."Cannot complete this action. The URL 'SitePages/Ahnet.aspx' is invalid. It may refer to a nonexistent file or folder, or refer to a valid file or folder that is not in the current Web."

Comment: Try this fix http://www.chaitumadala.com/2011/05/sharepoint-2010-server-error-url-is.html and retry publishing the page.

Comment: I did publish but problem is still the same. I will look at logs. Maybe I can find something there?